Output array from TFlite model result in confidence values >= 0.03, is the issue the way of interpreting of the output or is the model just that bad?
I'm running objection detection in an android app (Android Studio 3.6.3). I trained a Yolov5s model on my dataset, converted yolov5 (.pt model) into a tensorflow model(.pb file) and then converted tensorflow model (.pb model) to tflite model. I put the tflite model into Neutron to show the input and output formats. Input tensor: float32[1,416,416,3] and output tensor: float32[1,10647,15].(Number of classes is 10)
Here is the related code for the implementation of the model:
public ArrayList<Recognition> recognizeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, true);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer_ = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(resizedBitmap);

        Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();

//        float[][][] outbuf = new float[1][output_box][labels.size() + 5];
        if(outData != null){
            outData.rewind();
        }
        outputMap.put(0, outData);

        Object[] inputArray = {imgData};
        this.tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
        System.out.println(outputMap.get(0));

        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = (ByteBuffer) outputMap.get(0);
        System.out.println(byteBuffer);
        byteBuffer.rewind();

        ArrayList<Recognition> detections = new ArrayList<Recognition>();

        float[][][] out = new float[1][output_box][numClass + 5];
        for (int i = 0; i < output_box; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numClass + 5; ++j) {
                out[0][i][j] = byteBuffer.getFloat();
                //System.out.println(out[0][i][j]);
            }
            // Denormalize xywh
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                out[0][i][j] *= getInputSize();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < output_box; ++i){
            final int offset = 0;
            final float confidence = out[0][i][4];
            int detectedClass = -1;
            float maxClass = -1;

            //System.out.println("Step 1");

            final float[] classes = new float[10];
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c) {
                classes[c] = out[0][i][5 + c];
                System.out.println("Classes: " + classes[c] + "label: " + c);
            }
            //System.out.println("Step 2");
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c) {
                if (Float.compare(classes[c],maxClass) > 0) {
                    detectedClass = c;
                    maxClass = classes[c];
                    //System.out.println("Worked");
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("Detected Class");
            //System.out.println(detectedClass);

            final float confidenceInClass = maxClass * confidence;
            System.out.println("Confidence in Label:" + confidenceInClass);
            //if (confidenceInClass > 0.3f) {
            if (true) {
                //final float xPos = out[0][i][0];
                //final float yPos = out[0][i][1];

                //final float w = out[0][i][2];
                //final float h = out[0][i][3];

                //final RectF rect =
                 //       new RectF(
                   //             Math.max(0, xPos - w / 2),
                     //           Math.max(0, yPos - h / 2),
                       //         Math.min(bitmap.getWidth() - 1, xPos + w / 2),
                         //       Math.min(bitmap.getHeight() - 1, yPos + h / 2));
                detections.add(new Recognition("" + offset, labels.get(detectedClass),
                        confidenceInClass, new RectF(0,0,0,0), detectedClass));
                System.out.println("Added a detection");
            }
        }

        final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = nms(detections);
        return recognitions;
    }

Here is a sample of my output:
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Confidence in Label:0.07734438
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.24962312label: 0
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.36127633label: 1
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.009640366label: 2
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.012948245label: 3
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.017327309label: 4
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.02965945label: 5
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.013364434label: 6
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.016227067label: 7
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.016084641label: 8
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.013731003label: 9
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Confidence in Label:0.033512164
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.20377788label: 0
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.3806851label: 1
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.022365153label: 2
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.021088094label: 3
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.03524673label: 4
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.027197272label: 5
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.026301265label: 6
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.023108363label: 7
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.021165967label: 8
05-31 14:15:26.295 I/System.out( 1713): Confidence in Label:1.0596556E-4
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.089509845label: 0
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.32252label: 1
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.028067112label: 2
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.07662904label: 4
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.080369145label: 5
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.045333594label: 6
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.04815796label: 7
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.038886726label: 8
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.11335358label: 9
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Confidence in Label:7.3026586E-6
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.032702327label: 0
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.16568777label: 1
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.058870316label: 2
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.07644129label: 3
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.04210958label: 0
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.08284086label: 1
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.08875045label: 2
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.03878793label: 3
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.04994312label: 4
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.11336252label: 5
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.13836324label: 6
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.058589727label: 7
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.024186313label: 8
05-31 14:15:26.296 I/System.out( 1713): Classes: 0.056479186label: 9

I had thought the output array's columns would be something like this x,y,w,h, confidence, label0, label1,...,label9.
The converted .tflite model is linked here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fuW63fmG-G1yF2r9suiI6pryaXw5qT4J/view?usp=sharing
